# Reduce spacing in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents

How can I reduce only the space shown in the picture?

[image]

My code is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%%%% change layout of \chapter*
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makeschapterhead}[1]{%
    %  \vspace*{50pt}%
    \vspace*{12pt}  % space above
    {\parindent 0pt \raggedright
        \normalfont
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        %            \vskip 40pt
        \vskip 12pt % space below
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \makeatletter
    \let\@makeschapterhead\save@makeschapterhead
    \makeatother
    \chapter{Résumé}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table des matières}
    %\end{spacing}
    \listoffigures
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Liste des figures}
    \listoftables
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Liste des tableaux}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Liste des abréviation et des symboles}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How is this related to the `titletoc` tag when you're not using that package? Your title is also misleading. The spacing you mark is about the title of the table of contents not spacing inside the table of contents it self.

Comment: There are a lot of way to do it. It's the space defined in the `\chapter` command. Do you satisfy the space for `\chapter{Résumé}`. They have same space definition. The only different is table of contents if the unnumbered chapter heading.

Comment: Show me please how to do it.

Comment: @moumou85 You are missing copy one line in the new answer. `\let\save@makeschapterhead\@makeschapterhead`

Comment: @Tom yes, i'm missing a copy of a line in the new answer. now all is OK. Thank you Tom and thank you very much Peter Wilson for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ToC title is set using `\chapter*`. If you want to change the before and after spacing you need to redefine the `\chapter*` like this:

```
 % tocspaceprob.tex  SE 648459

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%%%% change layout of \chapter*
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makeschapterhead}[1]{%
  %  \vspace*{50pt}%
  \vspace*{12pt}  % space above
          {\parindent 0pt \raggedright
            \normalfont
            \interlinepenalty\@M
            \huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
            %            \vskip 40pt
            \vskip 12pt % space below
            }}
 \makeatother

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Résumé}
\end{document}
```

** EDIT following the OP's new request **

```
% tocspaceprob.tex  SE 648459

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
% save original definition of \@makeschapterhead
\let\save@makeschapterhead\@makeschapterhead
% revise definition of \@makeschapterhead
\renewcommand{\@makeschapterhead}[1]{%
  %  \vspace*{50pt}%
  \vspace*{12pt}  % space above
          {\parindent 0pt \raggedright
            \normalfont
            \interlinepenalty\@M
            \huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
            %            \vskip 40pt
            \vskip 12pt % space below
            }}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
% revert to original definition of \makeschapterhead
\makeatletter
\let\@makeschapterhead\save@makeschapterhead
\makeatother
    \chapter{Résumé}
    \chapter*{Starred}
     Some text.
  \end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @Peter Wilson, I need to reduce only the sapce in the page of  "Table des matières" and not the other chapter*.

Comment: @moumou85 I have revised my answer. It would have been very helpful if you had been clearer about what you wanted. I hope that you will now accept it.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information.
When I use your code I get an error. I get problems with \listoftables.
I have revised my quetion, above is my new code

Comment: Why don't you provide an MWE (from `\documentclass..` to `\end{document}) that we can compile that shows your problem? There are no `table` or `figure` in your posted code. Why should I waste time adding them? Probably other missing things as well.